# Is pg_ident.conf working?

Tags: linux, postgresql

When i'm trying to run psql, is says:

```
psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.12
psql
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "testuser"
```

Here is my `pg_hba.conf`:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer    map=testmap
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Here is my `pg_ident.conf`:

```
# MAPNAME       SYSTEM-USERNAME         PG-USERNAME
testmap         testuser                postgres
```

And `postgresql.conf`:

```
data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main'
hba_file = '/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf'
ident_file = '/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_ident.conf'
external_pid_file = '/var/run/postgresql/9.3-main.pid'
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
max_connections = 100
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql'
ssl = true
ssl_cert_file = '/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem'
ssl_key_file = '/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key'
shared_buffers = 128MB
log_line_prefix = '%t '
log_timezone = 'UTC'
datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
timezone = 'UTC'
lc_messages = 'C'
lc_monetary = 'C'
lc_numeric = 'C'
lc_time = 'C'
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
```

PostgreSQL Version: 9.3.12

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of this map is for `testuser` to log in as the db `postgres` user.

In `pg_hba.conf`, the `map` keyword should apply to the `postgres` user.

Also in the psql invocation, `postgres` as a user must be explicitly given as argument.

This works for me:

pg_hba.conf:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer  map=testmap

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
```

Invocation:

```
psql -U postgres
```

Make sure to reload the service after modifying the config files.

Comment: this is really strange behavior

Comment: `testmap != testuser `

Answer (score 0):

One more step to Daniel's answer:

You need to add the map to `pg_ident.conf`:

```
testmap testuser postgres
```

in `pg_hba.conf`:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres        peer     map=testmap
```